# Netbeans default comment template

Tags: netbeans, documentation

When i begin new comment with /** and hit enter it expands to something like(depending on the thing im documenting of course)

```
/**
 *
 * @param <type> $param
 * @return <type> 
 */
```

How can i edit this template? I want to add there, for example, @author tag

Answer (score 0):

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html 
This might solve your issue

Comment: It didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

well in case you don't  want to make a whole plugin for netbeans like the comment above suggest there is not simple way. But you can make your own code template like this guy suggest http://forums.netbeans.org/post-60995.html&highlight=